# angular routerlink with '&' in route parameter value

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

Hi I'm having an issue where due to the fact I have a route param that contains a '&' character in it.  Here is my route config:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'work', component: WorkComponent},
  {path: 'who', component: WhoComponent},
  {path: 'process', component: ProcessComponent},
  {path: 'services', component: ServicesComponent},
  {path: 'project/:name', component: ProjectComponent}
];
```

Here is my link:

```
<button class="some-class" [routerLink]="'/project/R&D more text here'">R&D Things and stuff</button>
```

The first time the link is clicked everything works great, the correct route is activated and the name route param gets the full string value.  The issue is on a page refresh the router is changing the url to:

```
http://localhost:4200/project/R
```

Whats the best way to handle this routing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `encodeURIComponent("R&D some other text here")` to encode this properly.

So create a property in your Component:

```
url = `/project/${encodeURIComponent('R&D Some Other Text')}`;
```

And then in your template:

```
<button class="some-class" [routerLink]="url">R&D Things and stuff</button>
```

When you want to capture the `name` property of the route param, you can use ActivatedRoute, and then use `decodeURIComponent` to decode the `name`:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    .subscribe(params => {
      const name = decodeURIComponent(params['name']);
      console.log(name);
      ...
    });
  ...
}
```

Here's a [**Working StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uri-encode-activated-route-param?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.